# Android Activity Asynctask error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask, launcher

I have an application with two activies. First one is reading serial data from arduino using asynctask. When button is clicked on first activity it should start second activity. But when I click that button it's going to android launcher everytime. Meanwhile second activity also opened in background.

I don't understand why android launcher is opening but not showing second activity on screen.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
private class AdkReadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    public void pause() {

        degisken = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        while (degisken) {
            publishProgress(mAdkManager.readSerial());
            SystemClock.sleep(50);

        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        kapak2 = (int) progress[0].charAt(2);
        kapak1 = (int) progress[0].charAt(1);
        limit = (int) progress[0].charAt(0);
        tx5.setText("kapak1 : " + (int) progress[0].charAt(1)
                + " kapak2 : " + (int) progress[0].charAt(2) + " limit : "
                + (int) progress[0].charAt(0));
    }

}
    public void butonClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UDOOBlinkLEDActivity.this,
                        shortcuts.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("dil", dil);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Some code would be lovely right about now :)

Comment: I've added some code :)

Comment: You're calling startActivity() prior to putExtra() - Remove the first call and rely on the one at the end :) Also, what is "dil" ? There is no reference to it that I can see.

Comment: calling startActivity is already at the end. I copied wrong code before.

Comment: 'dil' is an integer variable that indicates language of the application. I declare it at the top of the activity class.

Comment: Any errors in logcat at all? And can you post the code where you call butonClick() please?

Comment: Out of interest what was it?

Comment: place of calling startActivity was wrong turns out it's not just a copy paste error and I add startActivity second activity's backpressed method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(UDOOBlinkLEDActivity.this,
                    shortcuts.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 // startActivity(intent); remove this line
 intent.putExtra("dil", dil);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Because twice you are calling `startActivity(intent);` and after that you are sending data and again startActivity. So problem occurs.

Comment: copy paste error it wasn't there already sorry thanks for answer:)